# Delete cascading constraints from result in Oracle's SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

How can I delete a record from the grid of Oracle SQL Developer (3.1) with the option to cascade constraints?

Comment: You can't. The option "cascade" is an attribute of the foreign key constraint. It's nothing you can enable on demand

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name add it as an answer, and if i don't get any other help i will mark it as accepted

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "delete with cascade" through SQL (and therefor not through *any* SQL client - including SQL Developer)

The option "cascade" is an attribute of the foreign key constraint.

It's nothing you can enable on demand

Comment: is there anything i can do to enable the deletion if fks are found without going through every fk and enable the cascade constraints?

Comment: @MaVRoSCy: the only option is to set the FK constraint to "cascade"